# Why do I get "Could not find 'railties' error with Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I start my Rails server using  `rails s`, I getting this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 10 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:22
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
bundle install
```

Then start your server with this command:

```
bundle exec rails s
```

Answer (score 6):

There might be something wrong with your rails install. Try `gem list`, if you don't see `railties` then re-install rails: `gem install rails`

Answer (score 2):

If you install a new gem don't forget to  `bundle install` and start your server again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you have to try re-install Rails.

Try `sudo gem install rails`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than one version of ruby on your machine? If so download rvm, use `rvm --default` to set a default ruby version, then check if you have all the needed dependencies (i.e. gems) associated with your default version of ruby. If not, then reinstall rails and the missing gems.